# Вопрос по классу-делегату и принимаемыми им параметрами

Tags: c#, делегаты

всем привет, только что начал изучать делегаты. имеется такой пример:

```
// Класс, метод которого будет сообщен с делегатом.
static class MyClass
{
    // Создаем статический метод, который планируем сообщить с делегатом.
    public static void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Строку вывел метод сообщенный с делегатом.");
    }
}

// На 21-й строке создаем класс-делегата с именем MyDelegate,
// метод, который будет сообщен с экземпляром данного класса-делегата, 
// не будет ничего принимать и не будет ничего возвращать.

public delegate void MyDelegate();  // Создаем класс делегата. (1) 

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyDelegate myDelegate = new MyDelegate(MyClass.Method); // Создаем экземпляр делегата. (2)

        myDelegate.Invoke(); // Вызываем метод сообщенный с делегатом. (3)

        myDelegate();        // Другой способ вызова метода сообщенного с делегатом. (3')

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

обратите внимание, на данную строку:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();  // Создаем класс делегата. (1)
```

данный курс предоставляется в виде видео-уроков, автор говорит следующее:

"обратите внимание, что метод (конструктор по умолчанию в нашем классе-делегате), который будет сообщен с этим экземпляром данного класса-делегата - **ничего не должен принимать** , и также **ничего не должен возвращать** "

**вот мой вопрос:** то, что конструктор по умолчанию класса-делегата :*ничего не должен принимать , и также ничего не должен возвращать " - это аксиома для всех делегатов при из создании*, **или** это конкретный случай из-за того, что данный делегат, в данном случае сообщен с таким методом:

```
public static void Method()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Строку вывел метод сообщенный с делегатом.");
}
```

- который ничего не принимает в качестве параметров  и является void т.е ничего не возвращает, и не повлиял ли данный метод  на принципы построения делегата и параметры его конструктора?
  Т.е в итоге это либо
- общая аксиома
- конкретный случай построения класса-делегата сообщенного с данным
  методом

вот в качестве ответа я хочу получить разъяснение и ответ, что из двух вариантов является верным.

Comment: Не смотрите видеоуроки, они ничему хорошему не научат.

Comment: Это конкретный случай построения делегата сообщенного с данным методом. Как я понял, он говорил просто про сигнатуру делегата.

Comment: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105).

Comment: @VladD, а вообще конструктор может что-то вернуть? ну кроме созданного объекта :)

Comment: @Grundy: Вот-вот :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас тип делегата объявлен как

```
public delegate **void** MyDelegate**()**;  // Создаем класс делегата. (1)
```

`void` означает что делегаты этого типа указывают на методы, которые ничего не возвращают.

`()` означает что делегаты этого типа ничего не принимают.

Например, если бы тип был объявлен как

```
public delegate int MyDelegate(string a, string b);
```

его можно было бы использовать для методов, принимающий две строки, и возвращающих целое число.

Comment: если бы рассказал, при чем тут конструкторы, было б здорово :)

Comment: @Grundy я сам не понимаю причем тут конструкторы